# PHPcassa insert randomly

Tags: php, cassandra, phpcassa

```
$column_family->insert('row_key1', array('col_name1' => 'col_val1'));
$column_family->insert('row_key2', array('col_name2' => 'col_val2'));
$column_family->insert('row_key3', array('col_name3' => 'col_val3'));
$column_family->insert('row_key4', array('col_name4' => 'col_val4'));
```

The problem is mystery when the insert function does not insert value in sequence, instead it would appear in jumpping order: `col_val2`,`col_val3`,`col_val1`,`col_val4`

It bad when I could do a properly `get_range()` value as some have appear to insert into other partition.

How do I make the code insert orderly?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve.  The row is the atom of partitioning, so yes, it's expected (and desired) that row1..row4 could be in different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the batch_insert functionality?

```
$column_family->batch_insert(array(
    'row_key1' => array('col_name1' => 'col_val1'),
    'row_key2' => array('col_name2' => 'col_val2'),
    'row_key3' => array('col_name3' => 'col_val3'),
    'row_key4' => array('col_name4' => 'col_val4')
));
```